# Roughly estimating arithmetic operations using floating-point arithmetic

Tags: exponentiation, estimation, floating-point

I am developing an arithmetic library that supports values in the range of $-9999999999999999999$ and $9999999999999999999.$ I'm looking for a fast way to estimate the result of slow elementary operations such as exponentiation, multiplication, and division so that results that fall too far away from this range are never computed. Once the results are always checked against that range, my goal here is just to eliminate cases that are $100$% sure to be out of the range given an error margin. Examples includes $100000 ^{100000}$, $999999999999.9999999999^{2}$, $9999999999999999999 ^{1.5}$.

My first attempt was using 64bits floating-point arithmetic to catch theses cases quickly. However, I'm not sure how to compute the error margin so that I'll never get false positives.

Could you guys help here?

Comment: Double precision arithmetic isn't sufficient to represent this range.

Comment: I know, but I believe it can be used to eliminate most cases that fall out of the range.

Comment: Besides double precision you can use logarithms to detect obvious out-of-range case.

Comment: @gammatester you mean calculating the number of digits, right? If so, I believe this solution is suboptimal, once the error margin would be too high.

Comment: Yes roughly, therefore the **obvious** in my comment. You can do better if you use real logarithms of your double precision bounds, but even in this case you must have safety bounds. Since the ultimate test is a overflow in the final computation, I see no pressing needs wo work too hard to exclude those cases in advance.

Comment: So, in practice, your suggestion is to check if `floor(log10(n)) + 1 > 19`, right? (given `log10` is the native function for computing base 10 log for double precision numbers)

Comment: Yes. Where $n$ would be the **result** of the operation, e.g. for multiplication $a\times b$ you would check $\log_{10}a + \log_{10}b$, for exponentation $b \log_{10}a$
etc.

Comment: Got it. So, it's better to compute `b * log10(a)` instead of `floor(log10(a ^ b))`   to get a more accurate result, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65427/discussion-between-marcos-passos-and-gammatester).